# Why boost::asio::async_write works well at the first time and something goes wrong for the second time?

Tags: php, boost, tcp, boost-asio, ipv4

I can successfully send out data via TCP by invoking `async_write` at first, whereas it goes wrong when the `async_write` is called again.
Here is the **[code snippet](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dce5d420482de6d)**:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

const std::size_t buf_size = 500*1024;
const int test_cycles = 1.024e5;

namespace asio = boost::asio;

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> send_data(buf_size);

  std::vector<char> recv_buf(buf_size);

  asio::io_service ios;

  asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1(ios);
  asio::ip::tcp::socket socket2(ios);
  asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, {asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 55557});
  socket1.connect({asio::ip::address_v4::loopback(), 55557});
  acceptor.accept(socket2);

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
  {
      auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      for(int j=0; j < test_cycles; ++j)
      {
            size_t written_bytes = 0;
            auto to_send_data = send_data;
            asio::async_write(socket1,
                asio::dynamic_buffer(send_data),
                [&](auto ec, auto n)
                {
                    if(!ec)
                    {
                        std::cout << "successfully sent " << n << std::endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    }

                    if(0==n)
                    {
                        std::cout << "send error" << std::endl;
                    }

                    written_bytes = n;
                });

            asio::async_read(socket2, asio::buffer(recv_buf),
                [&](auto ec, auto n)
                {
                    if(!ec)
                    {
                        //std::cout << "received " << n << std::endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    }

                    if(0==n)
                    {
                        std::cout << "received error" << std::endl;
                    }

                    if(written_bytes != n)
                    {
                        std::cout << "received is not same with the sent" << std::endl;
                    }
                });
                
                ios.run();
                ios.reset();
        }
        
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float> elapsed = end - start;
        std::cout << elapsed.count() << " seconds\n";
        std::cout << (buf_size * test_cycles / elapsed.count() / 1024 / 1024/ 1024) << " GB/s\n";
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
successfully sent 512000
successfully sent 0
send error
```

***Some hint***

I found a **workaround** method and the program goes well.Here is the related code snippet:

```
        auto to_send_data = send_data;
        asio::async_write(socket1,
            asio::dynamic_buffer(to_send_data),
```

Why the aforementioned code snippet goes wrong?

**UPDATE**:

1. I try to set the breakpoint in the implementation of STD:: vector:: resize() via VsCode IDE(I did this test on Ubuntu. ), but the breakpoint does not work indeed(i.e the breakpoint is grey.). I could guarantee that binary program is built as debug mode. I also try to set the breakpoint by GDB, but GDB outputs "Function "std::vector::resize" not defined."
2. I set breakpoints in the implementation of the aforementioned operator(), I found the **default** has **never** been triggered indeed, in other words, start is always 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately [boost documentation on dynamic_buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/DynamicBuffer_v2.html) is extremely laconic:

> A dynamic buffer encapsulates memory storage that may be automatically resized as required.

meaning that dynamic_buffer will manipulate the underlying vector during IO operations.

[Boost ASIO tutorial](https://dens.website/tutorials/cpp-asio/dynamic-buffers) is more explicit:

> Dynamic buffer is a concept. Dynamic buffer is a buffer that you can write data into or read from it. If the buffer isn't big enough to fit your data then it will resize (grow) dynamically. So when you write into the dynamic buffer you don't have to worry if there is enough space left in the buffer. On the other hand, when you read data from a dynamic buffer, **you are responsible to throw away (consume) bytes read and no longer needed so the buffer won't grow permanently**.

Write operation on dynamic buffer in boost calls `consume` method of dynamic_buffer that erases `bytes_tranferred` from it:

```
class write_dynbuf_v2_op
   ....
   void operator()(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
       std::size_t bytes_transferred, int start = 0)
   {
     switch (start)
    {
      case 1:
         // write operation
         async_write(stream_, buffers_.data(0, buffers_.size()),
               BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(CompletionCondition)(completion_condition_),
               BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(write_dynbuf_v2_op)(*this));
        return;
     default:
        // write completed, consume transferred bytes and call handler
        buffers_.consume(bytes_transferred);
        handler_(ec, static_cast<const std::size_t&>(bytes_transferred));
  }
}
```

Hence in the original example, we would queue an async write on the vector, then queue async operation on the *same* vector again and again.
After the first callback finishes, transferring 512000 bytes, the second callback has an empty vector (as it was erased by dynamic_buffer) and the callback prints

> Successfully sent 0

As the error code is 0 and then

> Send error

As `send error` is printed when the number of bytes transferred is 0.

`io_context.run()` is stuck as it has a pending read operation.

The workaround helps as we schedule a copy of the vector for each async_write operation.
An alternative would be resizing the vector back to the original size after `io_context.run()`

Comment: **Yes**, [the size of the vector is zero after it has been sent out by async_write()](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96bc67c7f229fe97).  I don't quite understand the code snippet about the implementation about write_dynbuf_v2_op (e.g: what's `case 1`?). Could you please explain that more in detail for me?

Comment: This is a quote from boost implementation. The implementation of the async io write goes through two stages - `int start=0` `case 1` which should really be `bool writeBytes=false` and `if (writeBytes)` and `default` case that handles callback when the bytes are actually transferred. The `default` case erases part of the dynamic buffer and calls the handler that was supplied to the original `async_write` call

Comment: The asynchronous write consists of two stages - calling operating system/library function to write some bytes somewhere and a callback that gets called when the operation completes. In boost, those are handled by the same operator. Boost would call either itself or the operating system when (`int start =1`) to transfer bytes and will call the callback otherwise.

Comment: 1. If I understand you correctly, two stages should be done in sequence, first, calling operating system/library function to write , second, invoking the callback function after the write function returns. Am I right? 
    2.As far as I know, the write() function on Linux does not guarantee the data has been delivered out, it just returns when the data has been written to the corresponding driver. Do you agree with me?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. yes, though I am not sure if it is related to asio implementation. All I wanted to highlight with the snippet is that boost implementation calls `consume` on the dynamic buffer before user-supplied handler.

Comment: I see. Thank you. One more question, how do you effectively locate the corresponding source code for async_write(..,dynamic_buffer,...). I did try to find it, but failed. It's really a **hard** work for me.

Comment: I knew that the vector is resized to 0, if i did not, i would have examined locals in the debugger. Once the reason is identified, it is possible to set breakpoints on resize and erase methods of vector and examine the call stacks.

Comment: 1. I try to set the breakpoint in the implementation of STD:: vector:: resize() via VsCode IDE(I did this test on Ubuntu. ), but the breakpoint does not work indeed(i.e the breakpoint is grey.). I could guarantee that binary program is built as debug mode. I also try to set the breakpoint by GDB, but GDB outputs "Function "std::vector<char>::resize" not defined."  2.  I set breakpoints in the implementation of the aforementioned `operator()`, I found the `default` has **never** been triggered **indeed**, in other words, `start` is always 1.

Comment: The breakpoint within the callback would lead you to the correct `operator()` as it is invoked directly from it. Resize is indeed never called, since `consume()` uses `erase()`

Comment: Thank you so much. It **works** indeed. My understanding of this matter is at a different level with your generous help. If I [change `std::vector` to `boost::array`, it unexpectedly can repeatedly send out data.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62f2a7b99972782d). ***Why***?